# UIButton does not change its state when pressed when on top of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

Is there something different when you add a UIButton on top of a UITableView?  Or is my code for adding the UIButton incorrect that's causing the button to not look like it gets selected

```
    let addStudentButton = UIButton()
    addStudentButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let views = ["addStudentButton": addStudentButton]
    var allConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    addStudentButton.setTitle("hi", for: .normal)
    //        addStudentButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(StudentsViewController.addStudent), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    addStudentButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
    addStudentButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.flatWhite(), for: .normal)
    addStudentButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.flatWhite(), for: .selected)
    addStudentButton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.flatForestGreen().cgColor
    addStudentButton.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
    addStudentButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    addStudentButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
    allConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[addStudentButton(>=44)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    allConstraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[addStudentButton(>=44)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(allConstraints)
    studentsTableView.addSubview(addStudentButton)

    addStudentButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
    addStudentButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.layoutMarginsGuide.rightAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
```

I basically have a UITableView that lists students and I want a button on the bottom right of the screen that sits on top of the UITableView that can be selected.  The button looks fine until I press it then it never has that selected look where the text changes color and stuff.

Comment: In my opinion, if the .selected state does not turn automatically, you need to set .selected manually.

Comment: @nynohu how do you set it manually?  I don't have a different background image or anything...

Comment: You should set `addStudentButton.selected = !addStudentButton.selected` in your selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are:

- `let addStudentButton = UIButton()` makes a `.custom` button, which does not automatically change when tapped
- Your title color is the same for all states, thus specifically preventing any change of title color anyway
- A tapped button is highlighted, not selected